# For loop to add multiple JLabels

Tags: java, user-interface, for-loop

I would like to create a grid with pictures in it and I would like to know if you could make a for loop to do this more efficiently. I have done the first few pictures manually but it will take a lot of code to add all of them. I have 7 JPanels and each panel must contain 7 JLabels which are each set as an image(numbered and starting at 4).

```
{
JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
label1.sedIcon(new ImageIcon("4.jpeg"));
p1.add(label1);

JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("5.jpg"));
p1.add(label2);

JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
label3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("6.jpg"));
p1.add(label3);

JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
label4.setIcon(new ImageIcon("7.jpg"));
p1.add(label4);

JLabel label5 = new JLabel();
label5.setIcon(new ImageIcon("8.jpg"));
p1.add(label5);

JLabel label6 = new JLabel();
label6.setIcon(new ImageIcon("9.jpg"));
p1.add(label6);


JLabel label7 = new JLabel();
label7.setIcon(new ImageIcon("10.jpg"));
p1.add(label7);

JLabel label8 = new JLabel();
label8.setIcon(new ImageIcon("11.jpg"));
p1.add(label8);

JLabel label9 = new JLabel();
label9.setIcon(new ImageIcon("12.jpg"));
p2.add(label9);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 4; i < 13; ++i) {
    JLabel l = new JLabel();
    l.setIcon(new ImageIcon(i + ".jpeg"));
    p1.add(l);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This allows me to add all of the images in 7 for loops which is a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

You can so something like following

```
    JPanel[] jpanels = new JPanel[7];
    for(JPanel panel : jpanels) {
        int imageNo = 4;
        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imageNo + ".jpg"));
            imageNo++;
            panel.add(label);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = 7;
JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[value];
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[panels.length];
String fileExtension = "jpg";
for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i] = new JLabel();
    labels[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(i + "." + fileExtension));
    panels[i].add(labels[i]);
}
```